# Header, sidebar, content h-screen layout with TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a Tailwind layout that has a fixed height header, and a fixed width sidebar and content, where the header stays at the top of the page and the sidebar and content area scroll. I think I've gotten the basics down:

```
<div class="flex flex-col h-screen">
  <header class="bg-green-500 h-20 shrink-0">
    header
  </header>
  <div class="flex flex-row h-full">
    <aside class="bg-red-500 w-1/3 overflow-y-scroll">
      aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside<br>aside
    </aside>
    <main class="bg-blue-500 w-2/3 overflow-y-scroll">
      main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>main content<br>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

[(jsfiddle here)](https://jsfiddle.net/9mb51ynj/1/)

But there's still a scroll on the body of the document for the height of the header. This is for an Airbnb-style page, where there will be dozens of listings in the `<aside>` and a map in `<main>`, so it's important for both to just take up the vertical space left over in the document after the header's height, and to not exceed that amount and instead do `overflow-y: scroll`.

To be clear, if the `<aside>` or `<main>` content doesn't vertically fill all of the space, it should be stretched to fill it. But if the content of those elements exceeds the vertical space of the document (minus the header), they should be clamped and the overflow should be scrolled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is very close, you can just change `h-full` in the div beneath your header to be `h-[calc(100vh-5rem)]` the 5rem is the exact fixed height of your header.

You may also want to change `overflow-y-scroll` to `overflow-y-auto` this way it hides the scroll bars if content is not enough to fill (unless you like the bars).

Here's an example on Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/g7Xwd6begg

Comment: Oh wow, didn't know I could be that dynamic with Tailwind class names. That works a treat, thank you!

Comment: How do you know that `5rem` is `h-20`?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze Tailwind lists their default spacing scale here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-spacing#default-spacing-scale but in general you don't need their scale if you understand that each positive integer represents `.25rem` so `[any_spacing_utility]-4` is equal to `1rem` and so on.